# Reactive webflux only reading single line

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming

My task is to read a CSV file line by line and store that data in a database. for this, I have written below code:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity> readFromFileAndStoreData()  {
       
        readLinesFromCsv()

                .buffer(100)
                .flatMap(lines -> {
                    String[] headers = lines.get(0).split(",");
                    log.info("headers to read, headers:{}", Arrays.toString(headers));
                    return Flux.fromIterable(lines)
                            .log()
                            .skip(1)
                            .map(line -> {
                                MyPojoData myPojoData = convert(headers, line.split(",")); //converting to POJO
                                return myPojoData;
                            })
                            .collectList()
                            .doOnNext(r -> log.info("total records to store:{}",r.size()))
                            .flatMap(myPojodata -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> myDataRepository.saveAll(myPojodata))
                                    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty()));
                })
                .subscribe();


        return null;
    }
    private Flux<String> readLinesFromCsv(){
        return Flux.using(() -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:mycsvFile.csv").getInputStream())),
                        reader -> Flux.generate(() -> {
                            String line= reader.readLine();
                            return line;
                        }, (buffer, fluxSink) -> {
                            log.info("buffer check");
                            if (buffer != null) {
                                log.info("buffer not null");
                                fluxSink.next(buffer);
                            } else {
                                log.info("buffer completed");
                                fluxSink.complete();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }),
                        reader -> {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Exceptions.propagate(e);
                            }
                        })
                
                .map(buffer -> buffer.toString());

    }
```

but my `Flux.generate` only reading the first line from my csv whereas my CSV has more than 2k lines

Comment: read the docs of `Flux#generate` the first parameter is the generator function, it is only called once, as in your case, only reading one line. Its shown here in the docs https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.generate use the generator function to initialize your buffer, then in the second parameter function you read the lines and accumulate.

Comment: @Toerktumlare : is it possible for u to update above example?

Comment: No, im not going to write your code. Good luck